# Issue with Sorting NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, sorting, nsmutablearray

I have an NSMutableArray which contains an NSDictionary, I need to sort the array based on certain criteria.

Sorting criteria is

1. sort based on `properties.property.value`, suppose if I want to sort based on **properties.property.name = Risk** value. I want all the elements with Risk value first with the value in Ascending order. That means for the Dictionary which doesn't have
   `properties.property.name = Risk` must come last. Some of the dictionaries don't have these names.

Please help...

```
finalArr (
    {
    ViewTag = 101;
    "action-taken-date" =         {
        class = "java.util.GregorianCalendar";
        text = "2013-06-03 22:23:28.0 PDT";
    };
    alarms = 0;
    alerts = 0;
    application =         {
    assignee = "Test Name";
    completed = false;
    "properties" =         {
        class = "java.util.ArrayList";
        property =             (
                            {
                label = Risk;
                name = Risk;
                value = "3 - Low";
            },
                            {
                label = "Start Time";
                name = "Start Time";
                value = "05/09/13 06:00:00";
            }
        );
    };

    {
    ViewTag = 102;
    "date" =         {
        class = "java.util.GregorianCalendar";
        text = "2013-06-03 22:23:28.0 PDT";
    };
    alarms = 0;
    alerts = 0;
    application =         {
    assignee = "Test Name";
    completed = false;
    "properties" =         {
        class = "java.util.ArrayList";
        property =             (
                            {
                label = Risk;
                name = Risk;
                value = "2 - Low";
            },
                            {
                label = "Start Time";
                name = "Start Time";
                value = "05/09/13 06:00:00";
            }
        );
    };

    {
    ViewTag = 103;
    "date" =         {
        class = "java.util.GregorianCalendar";
        text = "2013-06-03 22:23:28.0 PDT";
    };
    alarms = 0;
    alerts = 0;
    application =         {
    assignee = "Test Name";
    completed = false;
    "properties" =         {
        class = "java.util.ArrayList";
        property =             (
                            {
                label = Status;
                name = Status;
                value = "Pending Signoffs";
            },
                            {
                label = Priority;
                name = Priority;
                value = 3;
            }
        );
    };

{
    ViewTag = 104;
    "date" =         {
        class = "java.util.GregorianCalendar";
        text = "2013-06-03 22:23:28.0 PDT";
    };
    alarms = 0;
    alerts = 0;
    application =         {
    assignee = "Test Name";
    completed = false;
    "properties" =         {
        property =             (
            {
                label = Priority;
                name = priority;
                value = 1;
            },
            {
                label = "Start Time";
                name = "Start Time";
                value = "05/09/13 06:00:00";
            }
        );
    };

{
    ViewTag = 103;
    "date" =         {
        class = "java.util.GregorianCalendar";
        text = "2013-06-03 22:23:28.0 PDT";
    };
    alarms = 0;
    alerts = 0;
    application =         {
    assignee = "Test Name";
    completed = false;
    "properties" =         {
        property =             (
                            {
                label = Status;
                name = Status;
                value = "Pending Signoffs";
            },
                            {
                label = Priority;
                name = Priority;
                value = 2;
            }
        );
    };
)
```

Comment: When you are finding it difficult to work with, there is something wrong with the design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this

```
NSString *risk = @"Risk";
[finalArray sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSDictionary * dict1, NSDictionary * dict2) {

    NSDictionary *property1 = dict1[@"properties"][@"property"][0];
    NSString *name1 = property1[@"name"];

    NSDictionary *property2 = dict2[@"properties"][@"property"][0];
    NSString *name2 = property2[@"name"];

    if ([name1 isEqualToString:name2]) {
        //if both names are equal then they are sorted based on value
        NSString *value1 = property1[@"value"];
        NSString *value2 = property2[@"value"];
        return [value1 compare:value2 options:NSNumericSearch];
    }else if ([name1 isEqualToString:risk]){
        //if name1 is equal to risk it is moved up
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    }else{
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    }

}];
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have multiple different requirements (logic) which go into determining the desired sort result. You should write your own comparison logic and use one of the array methods like `sortUsingComparator:`.